# Why do video players appear different on ios and Android?

Tags: video, ios

On some video sites, the video player on ios has different features to the played on Android.

I thinking specifically about a player that has a +10 second skip feature on ios but not on Android.

Is this something that owners of the video website could fix? Or is it an Android issue and out of their hands?

Sorry I don't know anything about video players so any information or clarification would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you mention some sites and browsers that exhibit this behavior? If it's on web sites, then it's usually under the control of media player embedded in the site and possibly the browser implementation, not using any OS media player.